# Can RAMPS V1.4 with DRV8825 drivers run 10 motors?

Tags: diy-3d-printer, ramps-1.4, stepper-driver

We need to drive 10 motors for our 3D printer. My doubt here is, RAMPS offer only one driver position for X, Y, Z. But I need multiple X, Y, Z. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

RAMPS is getting pretty outdated and is nothing more than a shield on top of the relative simple and limited ATMega 2560 microcontroller. Nowadays, 32-bit microprocessors are more common, more powerful and have more pins to be used for various tasks, like running multiple steppers.

However, you could use several RAMPS boards if you acquire a Raspberry Pi to run Klipper printer software, Klipper can control multiple RAMPS boards from the Raspberry Pi.